# Find and change value in excel multiple

Tags: excel, vba

I have two same number I want to sort after, but I want to change only one of them.

```
Sub replace_sales()

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For i = 1 To 10000
        If ws.Cells(i, 1) = "1932597" Then
            ws.Cells(i, 9) = "0"
        End If
    Next i
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: in your question if condition made you change ws.Cells(i, 9) to "0".After change take place which range do you want to sort, based on which column and how (ascending descending)?Also i think is better to use .VALUE if you refer to cell value.

Answer (score 0):

just place and `Exit For` to exit the current `ws` sheet loop at first matching:

```
Sub replace_sales()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For i = 1 To 10000
            If ws.Cells(i, 1) = "1932597" Then
                ws.Cells(i, 9) = "0"
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for help but how can I but it in this Code